# what is the ascii code of windows key?

Tags: c#, ascii

what is the ascii code of windows key? in my c# application I want to lock or disable windows key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually keys like the Windows key don't have an ASCII value. Only keys that are 'printable' have an ASCII value. To detect keys like the Windows key you have to use either the KeyDown or KeyUp events and use the KeyCode to detect which key was pressed.KeyCode for this key is 93.

Ex:-

Private Sub txt_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 93 Then
msgbox "93"
End If
End Sub

Comment: http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=76247
Vitual key codes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645540

Comment: i got the keycodes as follows in my keyboard, left windows =91 and right windows =92

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can use the KeyCode :

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.LWin && e.KeyCode != Keys.RWin)
            MessageBox.Show("Hello " +  e.KeyData.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: its fine but how can i disable windows key?

Comment: You can't just disable a key. Your application only gets key _presses_ and then only if they're intended for you.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2009/04/26/disable-special-keys-in-win-app-c.aspx

I test it and it works fine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that they don't have ascii codes, but they do have key codes: `VK_LWIN` and `VK_RWIN` for the left and right one.

So for example in `Control.KeyDown` you'll get a [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx) that has a `KeyCode` property which you can compare with `Keys.LWin` or `Keys.RWin`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an Ascii-Code because the WinKey is not printable. However you can use the virtual key code of these keys [as described in the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645540).

Answer (score 0):

The Keycodes for left side windows key is 91 and for the right side windows key is 92

Reference link : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/5624/ascii-key-code-value.aspx